# C# Parallel Web Requests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I need to make these things.

- Output currently available 10 files(file names)
- Store the last 10 files locally and load it on app start-up.
- Delete any unnecessary/old files after syncing.
- Refresh the list automatically every 5 minutes using the following logic: Download the files in a parallel way, having 3 parallel downloads at all times. You shouldn’t run more than 3 tasks at a time and there should not be any download tasks explicitly waiting for each other.
- Errors should be handled gracefully and displayed to the user via console.

I start with this way from the code down below. It works fine but I am not sure if I am on the right way. With the first parallel, I make parallel web requests to get files, with the second I try to record files in temp files and after that write them to the folder.

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void Main()
    {
//Whit this class I get all uri's
        Provider provider = new Provider();
        ReadWrite(provider);

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        while (true)
        {
            watch.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(60 * 5 * 1000);
            ReadWrite(provider);
        }
    }



    static void ReadWrite(AisUriProvider provider)
    {
        var files = provider.Get().ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Constants.NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL },
            uri =>
                      {
                          //Create destinitaion path for new file
                          string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), uri.Segments.Last());
                          DownloadResult result = new DownloadResult() { FilePath = destinationFilePath };

                          #region Get file size  
                          WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                          webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
                          long responseLength;
                          using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
                          {
                              responseLength = long.Parse(webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length"));
                              result.Size = responseLength;
                          }
                          Console.WriteLine($"File Size: {result.Size}");
                          #endregion

                          if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                          {
                              File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
                          }

                          using (FileStream destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.Append))
                          {
                              ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> tempFilesDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

                              #region Calculate ranges  
                              List<Range> readRanges = new List<Range>();
                              for (int chunk = 0; chunk < Constants.NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL - 1; chunk++)
                              {
                                  var range = new Range()
                                  {
                                      Start = chunk * (responseLength / Constants.NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL),
                                      End = ((chunk + 1) * (responseLength / Constants.NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL)) - 1
                                  };
                                  readRanges.Add(range);
                              }


                              readRanges.Add(new Range()
                              {
                                  Start = readRanges.Any() ? readRanges.Last().End + 1 : 0,
                                  End = responseLength - 1
                              });

                              #endregion

                              DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

                              #region Parallel download  

                              int index = 0;
                              Parallel.ForEach(readRanges, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Constants.NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL }, readRange =>
                              {
                                  HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
                                  httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                                  httpWebRequest.AddRange(readRange.Start, readRange.End);
                                  using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                                  {
                                      string tempFilePath = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                                      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                                      {
                                          httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fileStream);
                                          tempFilesDictionary.TryAdd((int)index, tempFilePath);
                                      }
                                  }
                                  index++;

                                  result.ParallelDownloads = index;

                                  result.TimeTaken = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
                              });

                              #endregion



                              #region Merge to single file  
                              foreach (var tempFile in tempFilesDictionary.OrderBy(b => b.Key))
                              {
                                  byte[] tempFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile.Value);
                                  destinationStream.WriteAsync(tempFileBytes, 0, tempFileBytes.Length);
                                  File.Delete(tempFile.Value);
                              }
                              #endregion



                          }
                      });


    }
}
```

Comment: webrequests are "waiting for something", not "doing something", so  Tasks would be a better solution than threads in terms of scalability and performance. (plus: hypothetically, on a single-core machine, your requests would run sequentially with `Parallel`)

Comment: What strikes me as problematic is the nested `Parallel.ForEach` loops. This is rarely a good idea, because it over-parallelizes the workload. Most probably will cause the immediate saturation of the `ThreadPool`. If you decide to keep it, you could consider using the `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` method to increase the number of threads that the `ThreadPool` creates immediately on demand.

Comment: Any chance for a [mcve]?